# How to dynamically set the Flask Session timeout?

Tags: python, session, flask, flask-session

In my Flask application I typically set the timeout for the session in the beginning of the code:

```
session.permanent = True
app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```

I need to set the timeout depending on the user’s permissions after logging in. Where is the best place to add this code so that I can dynamically change the session lifetime variable? I was thinking maybe after_request, but I only need this to run after a single particular login request....

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend adding it at before_request and checking permissions on each request to set the timeout.

```
@app.before_request
def make_session_permanent():
    session.permanent = True
    app.permanent_session_lifetime = timedelta(minutes=5)
```